# Python: None type error while subtraction

Tags: python, nonetype

I need to calculate difference between 'player_number' and 'comp_number' but it says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'NoneType' and 'int'

I understand this error. My code generates player_number is None type that is why I can not subtract it.

How can I handle this problem? Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
def name_to_number(name):
   if name == "rock":
       name =  0
   elif name == "paper":
       name = 1
   elif name == "Spock":
       name = 2
elif name == "lizard":
       name = 3
elif name == "scissors":
       name = 4
else:
    print 'Name is not listed:',name

def number_to_name(number):
if number == 0:
    print "rock"
elif number == 1:
    print "Spock"
elif number == 2:
    print "paper"
elif number == 3:
    print "lizard"
elif number == 4:
    print "scissors"
else:
    print 'Your number is not valid:',number


def rpsls(player_choice):
if player_choice == "rock":

    print 'Player choses', player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
elif player_choice == "Spock":
    print 'Player choses',player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
elif player_choice == "paper":
    print 'Player choses',player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
elif player_choice == "lizard":
    print 'Player choses',player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
elif player_choice == "scissors":
    print 'Player choses',player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
else:
    print "Name not in list",player_choice

import random
comp_number = random.randrange(0,4)
if comp_number == 0:
    print "Computer choses",number_to_name(0)
elif comp_number == 1:
    print "Computer choses",number_to_name(1)
elif comp_number == 2:
    print "Computer choses",number_to_name(2)
elif comp_number == 3:
    print "Computer choses",number_to_name(3)
elif comp_number == 4:
    print "Computer choses",number_to_name(4)

diffrence =  player_number - comp_number

if  diffrence % 5 == 1 or 2:
    print 'Player wins!'
elif (diffrence % 5) == 3 or 4:
    print 'Computer wins!'
else:
    print 'Game tie'




rpsls("rock")
```

Comment: Are you taking `Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python`, Coursera ?

Comment: Instead of `print` use `return`.

Comment: yes. I am taking this course.

Comment: Do i have to use 'return' everywhere?

Comment: Please do fix the indentation in your code example though.

Comment: At least in your functions `name_to_number` and `number_to_name`

Comment: ZdaR is correct. Additionally the if/else statements in `rpsls` are redundant, since the same logic is being used before and after the function call to `name_to_number`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762078/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-float)

Comment: Thank You guys! Solved that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this assigment

```
player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
```

But none of your `if/elif/else` cases in `name_to_number` use the `return` keyword. To `return` a value from this function, you would do

```
def name_to_number(name):
    if name == "rock":
        return 0
    elif name == "paper":
        return 1
    elif name == "Spock":
        return 2
    elif name == "lizard":
        return 3
    elif name == "scissors":
        return 4
    else:
        print 'Name is not listed:',name
```

The same goes for your `number_to_name` function

Comment: Worth explaining that in the absence of a return, `player_number` is just being set to `None` as the asker seems to not understand that this is why it's appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Untested Fix. 'return' statement was missing. Using the same variable name for a string and an int is not nice programming style.

```
def name_to_number(name):
   number = -1
   if name == "rock":
       number =  0
   elif name == "paper":
       number = 1
   elif name == "Spock":
       number = 2
   elif name == "lizard":
       number = 3
   elif name == "scissors":
       number = 4
   else:
       print 'Name is not listed:',name

   return number    #This line was missing
```